# Discover installation directory of any windows service

Tags: c#, service

I have a windows service that gets all the installed services on a workstation. Now I want to get the location of the executable file of a specific service. The path needs to be absolute. How can I achieve that programmatically?

Comment: "gets all the installed services on a workstation" - is that the *same* workstation as where your code is running, or a remote one?

Comment: If you enumerate the services via WMI, they have a [`PathName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Damien: yea is the same workstation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know about the .net interface but if you can't find a way you can read the registry value of each service: LocalMachine/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/*SERVICENAME*
and then you need to access ImagePath key which shows the full path (if not absolute then the base path is the windows home folder)

I found an example for that too: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/268807-get-path-install-service

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed this and this is what I created. Given, in this code I check for matching `imagePath` but it can be easily modified to return `imagePath` and it is already returns matching service name. You can in this loop `{foreach (string keyName...}` check the `keyName` and return `imagePath`. Works like a charm but remember that there will be security and user access considerations. It may fail if user has no access. My user runs it "as administrator", in this sense I do not have issues

```
// currPath - full file name/path of the exe that you trying to find if it is registered as service
// displayName - service name that you return if you find it
private bool TryWinRegistry(string currPath, out string displayName)
{
    displayName = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        using (RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services", false))
        {
            if (regKey == null)
                return false;

         // we don't know which key because key name is configured by config file and equals to service name
            foreach (string keyName in regKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (RegistryKey serviceRegKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(keyName))
                    {
                        if (serviceRegKey == null)
                            continue;

                        string val = serviceRegKey.GetValue("imagePath") as string;
                        if (val != null && String.Equals(val, currPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            displayName = serviceRegKey.GetValue("displayName") as string;
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```